# Cooking by the (black magic) book

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, music, find-the-order

...Now, for this alchemic recipe you will need the following ingredients:

**Liquid ones:**

> - A bottle of ■■■■. If you can, you shouldn't choose the strongest one - you'll need a plenty of it, because it will also give the sweetness to the cake.
> - A cup filled with ■■■■. Now, sure, you can use the water from other sources, especially if it's winter, but that will ruin all the magic.

**Lumpy ones:**

> - A pot full of ■■■■■ - I mean, any cake without it wouldn't be a cake anymore. Mix it with your own hands for more magic.
> - A bucket of ■■■■. You want your cake to the fattest, most calorious cake ever? I'm sure you do. If you don't, you can take several sticks of butter, but that ruins the magic again.

**Granulized ones**

> - A handful of ■■■■. Watch the nearby crows - they shouldn't eat it before you add them to the coldron.
> - A pinch of ■■■■ for the taste. Yes, even cakes need it, and it has nothing to do with magic.

**Special ones (magic, duh!)**

> - You need some ■■■■ in your cake - then the cake will make you feel correspondingly. If you, like a proper magician, have a long beard, you can donate some of it to the cooking. If you are a witch, you might prefer to use your black cat.

Bon appetit!

============

May you see, the magician constructing this list forgot to put the ingredients in proper order, so I can't cook it really (not that I wanted to eat that stuff, anyways). Oh, and he also erased the names of ingredients. But this won't be a problem for you, will it? Please, help me make a pretty cake.

=================

**Hint 1:**

> Every ingredient name consists of one syllable, seven syllables total.

**Hint 2:**

> Salt is the fifth ingredient.

**Hint 3:**

> The 'music' tag is here for a reason. However, the 'knowledge' tag would probably be too much.

Comment: Do the number of ■s matter, or are they just arbitrary?

Comment: @mestackoverflow Yes, those are letters indeed.

Comment: Salt is an anagram for last.

Comment: Wait, salt is the fifth, not the sixth?

Comment: @YoutRied Sixth of the random list here, rigth. What I am saying is if we put seven ingredients in the correct order (no stated here), salt will be fifth, not sixth.

Comment: Oh, ok. I get it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried a reverse approach and wondered how the music tag could fit in.
I came up with

> the musical scale *do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, si.*

This fits both that we search seven ingredients and gives us an order. With the given hints and by using some of the previously given answers, I found the following:

A bottle of ■■■■. If you can, you shouldn't choose the strongest one - you'll need a plenty of it, because it will also give the sweetness to the cake.

> MEAD (already answered by El-Guest) for **mi**

A cup filled with ■■■■. Now, sure, you can use the water from other sources, especially if it's winter, but that will ruin all the magic.

> RAIN (already answered by Quintec) for **re**

A pot full of ■■■■■ - I mean, any cake without it wouldn't be a cake anymore. Mix it with your own hands for more magic.

> DOUGH for **do**

A bucket of ■■■■. You want your cake to the fattest, most calorious cake ever? I'm sure you do. If you don't, you can take several sticks of butter, but that ruins the magic again.

> LARD (already answered by El-Guest and Quintec) for **la**

A handful of ■■■■. Watch the nearby crows - they shouldn't eat it before you add them to the coldron.

> SEED for **si**

A pinch of ■■■■ for the taste. Yes, even cakes need it, and it has nothing to do with magic.

> SALT (already answered) for **sol**

You need some ■■■■ in your cake - then the cake will make you feel correspondingly. If you, like a proper magician, have a long beard, you can donate some of it to the cooking. If you are a witch, you might prefer to use your black cat.

> could be FUZZ for **fa**, like suggested by SteveV in the comments

So the order would be

> dough, rain, mead, fuzz, salt, lard, seed

Comment: Wow!! This is a fantastic answer, great job! :D

Comment: Do you think Fa could be rot13(shmm)?  Kinda fits, but strange

Comment: I also normally use t for the seventh in the list rather than s, but yours fits really nicely! I like @SteveV’s suggestion too!

Comment: I was also not sure about the s/t for the last, but found the scale with both and s just fits better. I like @SteveV 's idea too and will add it to my answer.

Comment: could be [felt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felt)

Comment: WELL DONE good first answer keep it up at other puzzles

Comment: @ThomasBlue thank you for accepting my answer. I really liked your puzzle and therefore signed up here to answer it! :D Also thank you to the otheres who helped finding the missing ingedients!

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

> I noticed that *lard* for the second lumpy one and *hair* for the last one fits in with the number of blanks and the context of them.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a stab at this:

A bottle of ■■■■. If you can, you shouldn't choose the strongest one - you'll need a plenty of it, because it will also give the sweetness to the cake.

> This looks like some sort of alcohol, maybe a sweet WINE or a MEAD or something.

A cup filled with ■■■■. Now, sure, you can use the water from other sources, especially if it's winter, but that will ruin all the magic.

> This could be MILK (a stretch) because it's a liquid ingredient? It's water from a cow, I suppose; and you might not find cows roaming around in the winter.

A pot full of ■■■■■ - I mean, any cake without it wouldn't be a cake anymore. Mix it with your own hands for more magic.

> I think this is FLOUR, without flour it's not a cake.

A bucket of ■■■■. You want your cake to the fattest, most calorious cake ever? I'm sure you do. If you don't, you can take a bucket of butter, but that ruins the magic again.

> This is probably LARD, a fattier butter substitute.

A handful of ■■■■. Watch the nearby crows - they shouldn't eat it before you add them to the coldron.

> I was thinking that this was some sort of grain, maybe BRAN; or possibly something that crows eat, ie. NUTS.

A pinch of ■■■■ for the taste. Yes, even cakes need it, and it has nothing to do with magic.

> A pinch of SALT is a common expression.

You need some ■■■■ in your cake - then the cake will make you feel correspondingly. If you, like a proper magician, have a long beard, you can donate some of it to the cooking. If you are a witch, you might prefer to use your black cat.

> Long beards and black cats both have lots of HAIR.

So what do we have to put in order:

> MEAD/WINE, MILK, FLOUR, LARD, NUTS, SALT, HAIR. In alphabetical order it would be FLOUR, HAIR, LARD, MEAD, MILK, NUTS, SALT or FLOUR, HAIR, LARD, MILK, NUTS, SALT, WINE. But I think there's more to it than this (I also think I have a few of them wrong).

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Well, there's not much of a "track" in your solution, but I can say you guessed 3 words right. The order, however, is much more obscure and it enforces the correct choice of words (similar to my any other "pattern" puzzle).

Answer (score 2):

My take:

A bottle of ■■■■. If you can, you shouldn't choose the strongest one - you'll need a plenty of it, because it will also give the sweetness to the cake.

> WINE seems to make sense, although it could be some sweetener that's currently slipping my mind.

A cup filled with ■■■■. Now, sure, you can use the water from other sources, especially if it's winter, but that will ruin all the magic.

> Could be SNOW? But that could be the *other source*, in which case RAIN makes sense.

A pot full of ■■■■■ - I mean, any cake without it wouldn't be a cake anymore.

> I assume a cake has to have SUGAR - after all, it's a sweet dessert!.

A bucket of ■■■■. You want your cake to the fattest, most calorious cake ever? I'm sure you do. If you don't, you can take several sticks of butter, but that ruins the magic again.

> This is almost certainly LARD - the description matches and the expression is common.

A handful of ■■■■. Watch the nearby crows - they shouldn't eat it before you add them to the coldron.

> My guess is DUST? "Eat dust" is an expression.

A pinch of ■■■■ for the taste. Yes, even cakes need it, and it has nothing to do with magic.

> SALT for sure, the expression matches very well.

You need some ■■■■ in your cake - then the cake will make you feel correspondingly. If you, like a proper magician, have a long beard, you can donate some of it to the cooking. If you are a witch, you might prefer to use your black cat.

> This seems to clue HAIR.

My answers all together:

> WINE, RAIN, SUGAR, LARD, DUST, SALT, HAIR

Still looking for some connection.

Comment: Prob rain snow is not liquid

Comment: That's 3/7 as well.

Comment: Also it is not 'hair' for it has to do with 'feeling correspondingly'.

Comment: Changed snow to rain

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> The last granulized one is salt. It has four blanks and people call it a pinch of salt.